# What is the relationship between the function $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x)$ and linear regression?

Tags: statistics, regression

Consider the  function

> $$
> r(x) = \mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x)
> $$

This has been called the **regression function** in a textbook I'm using. I'm trying to figure out the relationship between this function and the classical linear regression model.

So, I know that it is a theorem* that we may write

$$
Y = r(X) + \epsilon
$$

for some random variable $\epsilon$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$.

Now suppose that we have

> $$
> Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon
> $$

This is the classical 1-dimensional regression function (assuming the $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ minimize the residual sum of squares).

**Question:** Is it then a mathematical theorem that if $Y$ is defined as above, that

$$
r(X) = \mathbb{E}(Y \mid X) = (\beta_0 + \beta_1 X)?
$$

And is *this* why the function $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)$ is called the "regression function"?

EDIT: The theorem that I am making use of is as follows (from *All of Statistics* pg. 89):

> Regression models are sometimes written as
>
> $$
> Y = r(X) + \epsilon
> $$
>
> where $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$. We can always rewrite a regression model this way. To see this, define $\epsilon = Y - r(X)$ and hence $Y = Y + r(X) - r(X) = r(X) + \epsilon$. Moreover, $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = \mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(\epsilon \mid X) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y - r(X)) \mid X) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E} ( Y \mid X) - r(X)) = \mathbb{E}(r(X) - r(X)) = 0$.

Comment: "it is a theorem that for any random variables $X$, $Y$ and any function $f$ on $X$ that: $Y = f(X) + \epsilon$ for some random variable $\epsilon$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$." Is it? What if $E(Y)\ne E(f(X))$?

Comment: @Did: See my edit above.

Comment: Then you need some serious rewriting along the line of: "for every random variables $X$, $Y$, there exists some function $f$ and some random variable $\epsilon$ such that $Y=f(X)+\epsilon$ and $E(\epsilon)=0$" (which is also bizarre, for other reasons, but at least true if one adds the condition that $Y$ is integrable).

Comment: @Did: I edited my question to accurately reflect the theorem. My question still stands at the end, however.

Comment: Are you asking why the regression model called this way?

Comment: @A.E: I'm asking if we necessarily have $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X) = (\beta_0 + \beta_1 X)$ when $\beta_0, \beta_1$ are the usual linear regression paramaters.

Comment: Necessarily linear structure?